# Error: Could not find module 'ExpoModulesCore' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator. Duplicate expo-modules-core

Tags: ios, xcode, package.json, npm-package

It appears I have two versions of expo-modules-core installed, which is likely causing this error: When i list the package it shows as follows:

```
npm list expo-modules-core
├── expo-modules-core@1.2.6
└─┬ expo@47.0.14
  └── expo-modules-core@1.1.1
```

I have tired the following:

```
npm uninstall expo-modules-core@1.2.6
npm uninstall expo-modules-core@1.1.1
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm prune
npm cache clear --force
npm install expo-modules-core@1.1.1
```

but then

```
npm list expo-modules-core
```

shows

```
├── expo-modules-core@1.2.6
    └─┬ expo@47.0.14
      └── expo-modules-core@1.1.1
```

I seem to be going round in circles - does anyone have a definitive answer on how to get rid of a duplicate expo-modules-core?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved it - adding an override to package.json

"overrides": {
expo-modules-core@1.1.1
},